# Method ‘Range’ of object’ ‘_worksheet’ failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting error while pasting the data . I do activate the workbook and sheet and like fully qualified. but not sure what I am missing here.
I am copying the data from 1 workbook to another. Sometimes it is working fine and sometimes I am getting the error. When the data is not copied , row number is set to zero. I am not sure why the data is not copied.

Sub PasteFormattedRange(rgFrom As Range, rgTo As Range)

```
Dim S                     As String
Dim rgStart As Range
Dim i As Long, CF_Format  As Long
Dim SaveDisplayAlerts As Boolean, SaveScreenUpdating As Boolean
Dim HTMLInClipBoard       As Boolean
Dim Handle As Long, Ptr As Long, FileName As String
Dim Rownum, Rownum1, Rownum2, Rownum3 As Integer


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  
With Workbooks("Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
      Set Rowfind = .Find(What:="CASH FLOW", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
      If Rowfind Is Nothing Then
         Rownum = 0
      Else
         Rownum = Rowfind.Row
      End If
      Set Rowfind = .Find(What:="VARIANCE $000'S", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
      If Rowfind Is Nothing Then
         Rownum1 = 0
      Else
         Rownum1 = Rowfind.Row + 1
      End If
End With

Set rgStart = Selection
rgFrom.Copy
DoEvents

'Enumerate the clipboard formats
If OpenClipboard(0) Then
    CF_Format = EnumClipboardFormats(0&)
    Do While CF_Format <> 0
        S = String(255, vbNullChar)
        i = GetClipboardFormatName(CF_Format, S, 255)
        S = Left(S, i)
        HTMLInClipBoard = InStr(1, S, "HTML Format", vbTextCompare) > 0
        If HTMLInClipBoard Then
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Application.GoTo rgTo
            DoEvents
            ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML"
            Application.GoTo rgStart
            Exit Do
        End If
        CF_Format = EnumClipboardFormats(CF_Format)
    Loop
    CloseClipboard
End If

With Newsheet.Columns(1)
        Set Rowfind = .Find(What:="CASH FLOW", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Rowfind Is Nothing Then
           Rownum2 = 0
        Else
           Rownum2 = Rowfind.Row
        End If
        Set Rowfind = .Find(What:="VARIANCE $000'S", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Rowfind Is Nothing Then
           Rownum3 = 0
        Else
           Rownum3 = Rowfind.Row + 1
        End If
End With

Workbooks("Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rownum & ":BL" & Rownum).Copy
Workbooks(newBook).Activate 
Newsheet.Activate   
Newsheet.Range("B" & Rownum2 & ":BL" & Rownum2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Newsheet.Range("B" & Rownum2 & ":BL" & Rownum2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Workbooks("Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rownum1 & ":BL" & Rownum1).Copy
Workbooks(newBook).Activate  
Newsheet.Activate  
Newsheet.Range("B" & Rownum3 & ":BL" & Rownum3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Newsheet.Range("B" & Rownum3 & ":BL" & Rownum3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

Comment: What is the value of `Rownum2` when it fails?

Comment: Yes ..it is zero and hence it failed.

Comment: I realised where the error is and posted the complete code. Please help.

Comment: There's no row 0. Row numbers start at 1.